# Finding Days Since Date in R from csv file

Tags: datetime, r, date, csv, statistics

I'm working with a factor of dates (dateframe$LastDate) brought in from the csv file and would like to calculate the days from today. Missing values are the norm with dates populating about 20% of 1000 rows.

Here's what I have so far which is returning me the factor of days since 1970.  It just feels like a lot of work to do a simple thing so I'm sure I'm off somewhere.

```
NumberOfDays <- ifelse(!is.na(LastDate), Sys.Date()-LastDate, as.numeric(""))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that LastDate is in date format initially. I'm not positive that as.numeric is required here.

```
LastDate = as.Date(c("2011-01-01", "2011-02-01", NA, "2011-03-01"))
NumberOfDays = as.numeric(Sys.Date() - LastDate)
```

If you want the NA's to be zero, use

```
NumberOfDays[is.na(NumberOfDays)] = 0
```

Comment: Now will that work the same on a factor since you have a vector defined?  or will I need to convert that to a vector first?  I realized the date issue but wasn't able convert the factor directly to a date.

Comment: @Rob: Seems like you could have just tried it yourself. But in case you don't have access to R at the moment: Yes, it works on factors too. As a test, you can just wrap the date vector from above in as.factor(). The result is the same as the original example.

Comment: Thanks Vincent.  I did try it and couldn't get it to work with my data.  I'm sure it was something I was doing.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your LastDate field is formated and read as date in R. You can do so with a code like:

`df$LastDate <- as.Date(paste(df$LastDate), "%y%m%d")`

Please note that in this case the LastDate field is "yymmdd" format, this code may change depending in your data.

Once you have it formated properly, you can create a new variable with plyr:

`df <- ddply(df, .(eventID), transform, NumberOfDays = Sys.Date() - LastDate)`

In this case you can use an eventID that uniquely identifies rows. If you have multiple identifiers they you can separate them by commas.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is great. Thanks a lot for the plyr direction. +1